# Unable to get function to output in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have the below code which is causing me some confusion.

The `itmLoop` function (I appreciate it isn't looping in the below extract) works when loose in the curly brackets in the `return` section, but doesn't output anything when called as below?

Once working I will need to make it recursive so have to keep this as an external function.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
const Output = () => {

  const items = [
   {title:"lvl1-1",
    children:[
      {title:"lvl2-1"},
      {title:"lvl2-2"}
    ]},
   {title:"lvl1-2"},
   {title:"lvl1-3"}
  ];

  function itmLoop(arr=[]){
    arr.map((e)=>{
      return (<span>{e.title}</span>)
    })
  }

  return ( { itmLoop(itms) } )

}

export default Output
```

Comment: You aren't returning from `itmLoop`.

Comment: @yaakov, just face palmed, thanks, knew it would be something simple I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yaakov for pointing my mistake out.

The `return` statement was missing before the `map` function.